# Displaying proper Boolean values in C

Tags: c, string

```
 //This program determines if a string is made up entirely of numbers.
 //It should output 1 if the string only consists of numbers and either
 //output 0 or nothing at all if otherwise. 
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdbool.h>

 bool check_num(const char *str) {
     for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i){ //Iterating through
         if (str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '0'){
             return false;  //Is this return statement correct?
         }
     }

     return true;
 }

 int main() {
     bool a = check_num("1");
     printf("%d\n", a);

     return 0;
 }
```

I'm trying to learn more about string manipulation in C. Whenever I run this code, the program outputs '0' instead of outputting '1' like I want it to unless I pass letters or symbols into check_num. What is going on here?

Comment: `str[i] > '0'` --> `str[i] > '9'`

Comment: Even though I assume you wrote this by hand to practice string manipulation, I should point out that [there's a standard library](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_isdigit.htm) function to check whether a character is a number, so you don't have to compare the character codes manually.

Comment: Note: `check_num("")`returns `true` which may be incorrect per your text definition .

Answer (score 1):

That should be

```
if (str[i] < '0' || str[i] > '9') {
//                            ^
```

Comment: Whoops, typo there on my end.